# GKE resources recreated on every `terraform apply` without any configuration changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm encountering a behavior with the Google Cloud Terraform provider where GKE resources are being recreated every time I run `terraform apply`, even though there are no configuration changes. I've detailed the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/15950), but I wanted to know if anyone here has come across this issue and found a solution.

**Environment:**

- Terraform v1.5.7
- provider.google v4.83.0
- GKE version: 1.27.4-gke.900

**Affected Resource(s)**

- google_container_cluster
- google_container_node_pool

**Terraform Configuration Files**

```
// Create a Google Compute VPC Network

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name    = var.vpc_name
  project = var.project_id

  auto_create_subnetworks                   = false
  network_firewall_policy_enforcement_order = "AFTER_CLASSIC_FIREWALL"
}

// Define subnetworks within the VPC Network
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnetwork" {
  count         = length(var.regions)
  name          = "${var.vpc_name}-subnet-${var.regions[count.index]}"
  ip_cidr_range = var.ip_cidr_range[count.index]
  region        = var.regions[count.index]
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "k8s-pod-range"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.2.0.0/16"
  }

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = "k8s-svc-range"
    ip_cidr_range = "10.3.0.0/16"
  }

  log_config {
    aggregation_interval = "INTERVAL_10_MIN"
    flow_sampling        = 0.5
    metadata             = "INCLUDE_ALL_METADATA"
  }

  private_ip_google_access = true
  #  private_ipv6_google_access = "ENABLE_OUTBOUND_VM_ACCESS_TO_GOOGLE" // Changed from "DISABLE_GOOGLE_ACCESS
}

// Define a firewall rule for the VPC Network
resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall" {
  name    = "${var.vpc_name}-firewall"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link

  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }

  source_ranges = [
    "130.211.0.0/22",
    "35.191.0.0/16"
  ]
}

# Define a Google Cloud router for each subnetwork
resource "google_compute_router" "cloud_nat_router" {
  # Create one router for each subnetwork
  count   = length(google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork)
  name    = "cloud-nat-router-${google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork[count.index].name}"
  region  = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork[count.index].region
  network = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link

  # Define BGP settings (note that ASN is hard-coded here)
  bgp {
    asn = 64514
  }
}

# Define a NAT configuration for each router
resource "google_compute_router_nat" "nat" {
  # Create one NAT config for each router
  count  = length(google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork)
  name   = google_compute_router.cloud_nat_router[count.index].name
  router = google_compute_router.cloud_nat_router[count.index].name
  region = google_compute_router.cloud_nat_router[count.index].region

  # Automatically allocate NAT IPs
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "AUTO_ONLY"
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "ALL_SUBNETWORKS_ALL_IP_RANGES"

  # Log configuration (logging is disabled, only errors are logged)
  log_config {
    enable = false
    filter = "ERRORS_ONLY"
  }
}

// Output variables for the VPC Network module

output "vpc_network" {
  value       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link
  description = "The self-link of the created VPC network."
}

output "vpc_network_name" {
  value       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.name
  description = "The name of the created VPC network."
}

output "subnetworks_name" {
  value       = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork[*].name
  description = "The self-links of the created subnetworks within the VPC network."
}

// Create a Google Container Cluster (GKE) in the specified VPC

resource "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name               = var.cluster_name
  project            = var.project_id
  location           = var.location
  min_master_version = var.master_version

  resource_labels = {
    "provider" = "gcp"
    "tier"     = "free"
  }

  # We can't create a cluster with no node pool defined, but we want to only use
  # separately managed node pools. So we create the smallest possible default
  # node pool and immediately delete it.
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1

  release_channel {
    channel = "STABLE"
  }

  network    = var.network
  subnetwork = var.subnetwork

#  enable_l4_ilb_subsetting = false

  binary_authorization {
    evaluation_mode = "PROJECT_SINGLETON_POLICY_ENFORCE"
  }

  master_auth {
    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }

  default_max_pods_per_node = 16

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = "k8s-pod-range"
    services_secondary_range_name = "k8s-svc-range"
  }

  network_policy {
    enabled  = true
    provider = "PROVIDER_UNSPECIFIED" // Consider setting the value to "CALICO"
  }

  enable_intranode_visibility = true

  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes    = false
    enable_private_endpoint = false
    master_ipv4_cidr_block  = var.master_ipv4_cidr_block
  }

  workload_identity_config {
    workload_pool = "${var.project_id}.svc.id.goog"
  }

  node_config {
    shielded_instance_config {
      enable_integrity_monitoring = true
      enable_secure_boot          = true
    }

    workload_metadata_config {
      mode = "GCE_METADATA"
    }
  }

  depends_on = [google_project_service.compute, google_project_service.container]
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Run `terraform apply` and observe that GKE resources are created.
- Run `terraform apply` again without making any changes.

There was no erros occured during the terraform apply process. Terraform should recognize that no changes have been made and should not attempt to recreate the GKE resources. However, Terraform attempts to recreate the GKE resources every time, even without any changes to the configuration.

Comment: What' the output of `terraform plan` ?

Comment: I'm experiencing identical behavior. Every time I run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, I get the exact same output: `Plan: 2 to add, 1 to change, 2 to destroy`. This happens even when I target a different module.

Comment: I ended up with the following workaround for now. By adding the `lifecycle { ignore_changes = all }` block to `google_container_cluster` and `google_container_node_pool` resources, Terraform is instructed to ignore all changes to these resources, preventing them from being recreated every time.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the which resources it says it will change and destroy.  Also, which version of the provider are you using?

Comment: Regarding the provider version, it is included in the environment details section above. I have also upgraded the provider to the latest one (v4.84.0) and still encounter the same issue. Please see the plan output attached to the following bucket: [plan_output.txt](https://storage.googleapis.com/to-be-used-for-stackoverflow/plan_output.txt).